# can people see Facebook IOS app on their facebook?

Tags: facebook

I've created an IOS app as a Facebook Developer. So my question:
Are people able to see the app when they go into their Facebook - like in the Browser? Or are Facebook IOS apps only something that you can see in the actual app on the iphone/iPad that I'm creating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether the Facebook developer configured a canvas facing site will show what the end user will see.

Any application made by a third party once set to public in app settings can be viewed by anyone.

If you app is made for iOS then either the user will see a misconfigured webpage or dialog asking whether the user wants to send to mobile. All of this of course depends on how the the developer of the application sets everything.

See the documentation for detailed information

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Comment: by canvas facing site, do you mean all the info I put in "App Info" at "App Details"?

Comment: @user3295588 yes that is one area.